# What's a suitable sealant for the garden slabs in the picture?

Tags: sealant

What is the best type of sealant I should get to fill the cracks between the slabs in the picture below?

I think these are concrete slabs that I have in my garden, and not sandstone, but I'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is grout in place now with some caulking where it's cracked out.  I'm going to guess that these bricks are set in a sand base? If so, then you'll never get the blocks stable enough to keep the grout from cracking.

Have you considered just removing the grout and applying some "paver sand" into the gaps?  That's a lot more forgiving than grout and a lot less trouble to maintain.

Otherwise, you'll probably want to go ahead and re-grout this after removing the old and cracked parts.  It will need to be updated regularly but I think the result will be better than just applying caulk or silicone sealer.

Comment: I have the same pavers in a 30 ft path; No grout, they haven't moved yet. Also easy to pick up to change anything.

Comment: It didn't crack until I tried to pressure wash it for the first time. Some of the grout (or sealant?) didn't crack at all under the full 180 bar pressure of the pressure washer. The blocks don't move no matter how hard I try to nudge them.

There are about 200 slabs like this in my garden, and only a few of them have this problem, so I'd rather not redo it all.